# Website which generates page for any offset

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have a series of pages on my website which are generated identically using php and a database.  The only thing that changes is which topic is selected from the database.  I want the user to be able to navigate to the each of these topic pages directly like `www.mywebsite.com/<TOPIC>` where `<TOPIC>` is the name of ANY topic.  So currently I have a source folder in my public html directory along with an index page for each of these topics.  As I'm about to add a lot more "topics" I feel like there is a better way to do this.

What I am looking for is for the user to be able to type `www.mywebsite.com/<TOPIC>` and a SINGLE php script is used to generate a page based on what `<TOPIC>` is.

The only thing I could think of was using the 404.php page for this and only showing an error if the topic didn't exist.  But with that idea, I don't know how I would get what `<TOPIC>` and feel like that is a hack.

Comment: a simple mod_rewrite rule, e.g. `RewriteRule /(.*) index.php?topic=$1`. It is a hack, but it's a very very very common hack.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming this is in .htaccess?

Comment: or httpd.conf. whever. for testing, use htaccess. once you're satisfied with how it works, but it in a .conf file, because .htaccess usage is a pretty big performance hit.

Comment: Would there be a way in the rule to exclude pages that were found?  (There are a few pages that are truly different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create or edit your `.htaccess` file in your document root and write this:

```
...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then you can call a page like:

```
http://example.com/this-is-my-topic
```

and in your index you would be able to handle `$_GET["page"]` with the value of `this-is-my-topic`.

That is of course only if your server supports `Clean URLs` and `mod_rewrite.c`

Comment: Two things: 1) Is there a reason why you're doing `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` instead of just a `.*`?  2) what is `[NC, L]` ?

Comment: 1) no reason at all 2) NC = case-insensitive

Comment: Ah nice! That's actually something I was looking for.  After your post @MarkB's comment I did some searching and found I additionally needed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to get exactly what I wanted.